# Launch external application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am building a local web application and I'd like to launch an external application with a button.
I've found this code which works in an .html file with Internet Explorer, but inside a show.html.erb it doesn't work, just shows the error message

```
<script language="javascript">
function LaunchApp(appPath)
{
    try
    { 
        WSH = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WSH.run(appPath);
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        errMsg = "An error occured while lauching the application.\n\n";
        alert(errMsg);
    }
    window.open('', '_self', '');
}
</script>
<button onclick="LaunchApp('C:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe')">Click me</button>
```

It'll be possible to make this launch the application?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
function LaunchApp(appPath)
  var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
  var commandtoRun = appPath; 
  oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,"","","open","1");
}
```

Comment: Tested, it doesn´t work in rails nor in .html. Included initial {.

Comment: Well, you'll better add some tags like [tag:internet-explorer] to the question, as it has actually nothing to do with rails.

Comment: The question is about launching an external application from rails. The code I included in the question works but not in rails.

Comment: check the generated HTML, if it does work outside of rails then figure out how the resulting html is different.